# How to hide rows from Yii2 GridView based on user permissions?

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to hide rows from a `GridView` based on user permissions (RBAC).
(`Yii::$app->user->can('readModel', ['model' => $model]);`)

I assumed i have to add some filters to the search model, but i can't find out how i can add this filter to the query.
Maybe there is an easier solution that i haven't found yet, like adding an argument to the `GridView` call?

Docs don't really help me understand this specific situation either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify how you're assigning your permissions to your users? i.e. roles and rights

Comment: I'm using the standard Yii2 `yii\rbac\DbManager`'s (using `Yii::$app->authManager`) `createRole` and `createPermission` methods to create permissions and roles. And use the `assign` method to assign users to a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way clould be based on  assign  a proper class to rows using row options

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        .........
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
   'rowOptions'=>function ($model){
        $class= (Yii::$app->user->can('readModel',  ['model' => $model]) ? 'hide' : 'swow';
         return $class;
    },
```

Comment: I'm going to keep this question open because i prefer a solution that doesn't add the rows at all over hiding them with CSS. But thanks for the **temporary** solution.

Comment: The reason why i prefer leaving out rows instead of hiding them, is that to me it seems bad practice to only "hide" something, which shouldn't even be accessible to the specific user. Sure, i also check for correct permissions in the controller, but i think the user should not even be able to find out it's existence. Your answer helps me out for now, but would (in my opinion) be bad practice in a live application. I will accept your answer as requested, but since i'm new to stackoverflow, would like to hear anyone else's opinion on this matter.

Comment: You have already the value in dataProvider  .. if you want filter the value before they are used in gridview you cannot   select  or remove form dataProvider ..   but if you have in gridview::widget or your write a new widget as you like or you can use only show  or hide .. . This because the gridveiw widget have not a prePopulate event for check is the row can be show /populated or  not  ...hope this is clear ..and useful

Answer (score 0):

As suggest the plurality of the attribute "rowOptions" is an array, lamba-function should return an array:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        .........
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
   'rowOptions'=>function ($model){
        $class= (Yii::$app->user->can('readModel',  ['model' => $model]) ? 'hide' : 'swow';
         // HTML tag attribute class
         return ['class' => $class];
    },
```